# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (L.channels() == 1 && I.channels() == 1) in connectedComponents_sub1

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.1, connected-components

I got the following error in OpenCV (python) and have googled a lot but have not been able to resolve.

I would be grateful if anyone could provide me with some clue.

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (L.channels() == 1 && I.channels() == 1) 
>      in connectedComponents_sub1, file /home/snoopy/opencv-
>      3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp, line 341
>      Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "test.py", line 30, in 
>      plant = analyzeplant.analyzeSideView(plant)
>      File "/home/snoopy/Desktop/Leaf-201612/my-work-
>      editing/ripps/src/analyzePlant.py", line 229, in analyzeSideView
>      plant_img = self.__extractPlantArea(plant_img)
>      File "/home/snoopy/Desktop/Leaf-201612/my-work-
>      editing/ripps/src/analyzePlant.py", line 16, in __extractPlantArea
>      output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(plant, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
>      cv2.error: /home/snoopy/opencv-
>      3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/connectedcomponents.cpp:341: error: (-215) >    L.channels() == 1 && I.channels() == 1 in function 
>      connectedComponents_sub1

Comment: Not without a [mcve], unfortunately.

Comment: What's a "rare" error?

Comment: following the below link, I added cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and the error  >Assertion failed (L.channels() == 1 && I.channels() == 1) in connectedComponents_sub1     >has resolved. `image = cv.imread("/home/snoopy/Desktop/Leaf-201612/cropped-image/cropped_125254_ver2.bmp",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`  did the job.  [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/96641/problem->using-connectedcomponents-in-opencv-3-using-visual-studio-2012/)    Thanks anyway-Wayne Werner

Answer (score 13):

Let us analyze it:

> Assertion failed (L.channels() == 1 && I.channels() == 1)

The images that you are passing to some function should be 1 channel (gray not color).

> __extractPlantArea(plant_img)

That happened in your code exactly at the function called `__extractPlantArea`.

> cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats

While you are calling the OpenCV function called `connectedComponentsWithStats`.

**Conclusion:**

Do not pass colorful (BGR) image to `connectedComponentsWithStats`

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the cause..fixed with `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` thanks Humam!